# automatically download csv files from a website and add to database

Tags: csv

I want to write a program that automatically downloads all the csv files on a webpage and then enter the data in those csv files into SQL Server. I have written the macro to enter the data from csv to SQL server. I just want you guys to help me in automatically downloading the files from a website everyday. is it similar to webscraping? I am new to web programming. So please guide me which languages to go through to do this

Comment: Please post the relevant section of the code that you're currently working on; folks will be glad to help, but won't write it for you.

Comment: I am working on Macros. I am using some other pc on which I dont have codes, so cant write codes as of now. I want to know through what language can I automatically download all the links of csv files on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [Python](http://python.org/), as usual.

After you figure out how to work with it, here are the modules I would use:

- [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) - for parsing CSV files.
- [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) - for downloading files.
- [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for database operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. What should I learn in python?anything specific? I need to do this in 2 days. So can you please guide me how to start and from where to start??

I am new to web programming. Can you guide me how to start web programming. Which site's tutorials to read and what software to use. What all languages should I learn as a beginner. I am familiar with C,C++,Core Java, SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy with PowerShell:

```
$web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$web.Downloadstring("http://<your url here>") | out-file $env:tmp\MyFile.csv
```

Then use

> Import-CSV

and the [SQLServer PowerShell provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281947.aspx) to inject your data into SQLServer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am new to web programming. Can you please guide me what language to learn to do this work? and anything specific thing required to do this. I have to do this work in 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend PowerShell way to do the job.

1. Download data from web by WebClient like @David Brabant said
2. Then Use Import-Csv to get data row by row `Import-Csv -Path file.csv`
3. In the end, make use of SQL Server PowerShell Module in your script to upload data into SQL Server `Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query '<sql statements>'`

Here exists a complete sample script for you to download and learn. [How to use SQL Server PowerShell Module to import data from CSV file](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-use-SQL-Server-0e32b08d)